# SSRS 2012 report rendering issue

Tags: reporting-services, rendering, subscription, mhtml

I'm setting up a report on SSRS 2012 with email delivery.

I want the report to be shown in the body of the email, so I'm using MHTML rendering. When I preview the report on the server it looks fine; but when i set up email delivery and look at the report in Outlook, it's not rendered correctly. There is a different font and formatting of text in a table, which is part of the report. When I try to render it using HTML and send it as an email attachement, it looks fine.

I should mention that this exact report was running on SSRS 2008, and everything worked fine.

Do you know what the problem might be?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have reputation to comment, so I will post as an answer.

The problem seens to be with Outlook since even if you paste a simple table from Excel the table get rendering issues as well.
I suggest you enlarge the cell width and test the HTML in the body of the e-mail until its okay.